# How to properly cast ExplicitListValues from apache POI dataValidators to test?

Tags: java, junit, casting, apache-poi

I've added dataConstraints to my Apache POI workbook's sheet. And now i want to add a unit test.

My constraint is a simple list of two values, "yes" and "no".

my current attempt:

```
Assert.assertEquals(
  Arrays.toString("yes,no".split(",")),
  Arrays.toString(dv.get(0).getValidationConstraint().getExplicitListValues()));
}
```

Fails with

```
expected:<[[yes, no]]> but was:<[["yes, no"]]
```

I am pretty sure I am missing something obvious on java typecasting logic, but can't put my finger on what.

--
edit 1:

I tried creating the List as

```
XSSFDataValidationConstraint c =
  (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(
  new String[]{"yes", "no"});
```

and

```
XSSFDataValidationConstraint c =
  (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(
  "yes,no".split(","));
```

it doesn't matter, the out put of `Arrays.toString( ...getExplicitListValues())` will always show the extra quotes!

-- edit2:

To try to figure this out, i created the list in the way that @axel-ichter suggests:

```
XSSFDataValidationConstraint c =
  (XSSFDataValidationConstraint) dvHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(
  "\"yes,no".split(","));
```

And then i get something else:

```
expected:<[[yes, no]]> but was:<[[""yes, no"]]>
```

-- edit 3

```
ArrayUtils.contains( ....getExplicitListValues(), "yes") // returns null;

...getExplicitListValues().getClass().getTypeName() // java.lang.String[]
```

Comment: How is that list constraint set? Would must be `...createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"yes", "no"})`. Seems to be `...createExplicitListConstraint(new String[]{"\"yes, no\""})`.

Comment: i am using (simplified here): `createExplicitListConstraint("yes,no".split(","))` because the list values comes from a resource/db that hold one single localized strings for each set.

Comment: Hm, but the result of your `dv.get(0).getValidationConstraint().getExplicitListValues())` looks more like `createExplicitListConstraint("\"yes,no\"".split(","))`.

Comment: I edited with all the ways i create it... can't really explain. maybe that is a bug in the POI code? pls, see my new, 2nd edit. The extra quotes are always there, even if i include the quotes as you suggested... then i get double extra quotes!

Comment: I have never suggested including extra quote marks. All i said was that it looks like as if the extra quotes are in your string already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cannot reproducing your issue. Using `apache poi 4.0.1` the following code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddressList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Arrays;

class CreateExcelDataValidationLists {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
  Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Sheet1");
  DataValidationHelper dvHelper = sheet.getDataValidationHelper();
  String constraint = "yes,no";
  DataValidationConstraint dvConstraint = dvHelper.createExplicitListConstraint(constraint.split(",")) ;
  CellRangeAddressList addressList = new CellRangeAddressList(0,0,0,0);          
  DataValidation validation = dvHelper.createValidation(dvConstraint, addressList);
  sheet.addValidationData(validation);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateExcelDataValidationLists.xlsx");
  workbook.write(out);
  out.close();
  workbook.close();

  Thread.sleep(1000);

  workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream("CreateExcelDataValidationLists.xlsx"));
  sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  List<DataValidation> validations = (List<DataValidation>)sheet.getDataValidations();

  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(validations.get(0).getValidationConstraint().getExplicitListValues()));

 }
}
```

Produces:

```
[yes, no]
```

---

Just tested. Same code using `apache poi 3.14` indeed produces

```
["yes, no"]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing! i am on 3.14. Might be an old bug? ...will try to update.

Comment: Confirmed! updated to 4.0.1 and all my problems went away!!! thanks a ton!